# How do I sort multiple strings in bash, using one string as the sortable parameter?

Tags: bash, sorting, text

I have a file that goes:

```
01:12:12:01
WRGHR
zxerty
00:01:02:03
GRAARGH
qwerty

...

00:59:59:01
URRGH
xqwrts
```

I want to sort this file using one string as the sortable parameter and having the rest be sorted with it.

My current best is:

`cat FILE.txt | tr '\n' '\t' | sed -E 's/\t(0[01]:)/\n\1/g' | sort -n  | tr '\t' '\n'`

This outputs:

```
00:01:02:03
GRAARGH
qwerty
00:59:59:01
URRGH
xqwrts
...
01:12:12:01
WRGHR
zxerty
```

which works, but can I do easier that this?

Comment: Amended question to include current, and desired, output.

Comment: The `cat` can go :-), `tr ... < file.txt | ...`

Comment: I'll explore this, thanks! Damn, I was trying to figure out what sort of a regex is ```:-)```

Comment: twa's a smiley not a regex.

Comment: You don't say? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can do this in a single command:

```sh
awk -v RS='([0-9]{2}:){3}[0-9]{2}\n' '
prt != "" {
   map[prt] = prt $0
}
{prt = RT}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
   for (i in map)
      printf "%s", map[i]
}' file

00:01:02:03
GRAARGH
qwerty
00:59:59:01
URRGH
xqwrts
01:12:12:01
WRGHR
zxerty
```

`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` sorts an array using index as string value in ascending order. Note that we are using date-time stamp as array index in associative array `map`.

---

OP's approach can be refactored to this to avoid dependency on `tab` which may be present in input:

```sh
tr '\n' '\1' < file |
sed -E 's/\x1([0-9]{2}:)/\n\1/g; s/\x1$//g' |
sort -t $'\1' -n |
tr '\1' '\n'
```

Comment: This is very nice! However, I can cobble my way in a few minutes, going from memory/logic, but I couldn't do yours unless I found it here and copy-pasted it. Is there no way to make it more intuitive? If my file hadn't had multiple newlines, I could cat | sort it in no time…

Comment: 1. This single command is much more efficient. You can compute timing on a few MBs of input. 2. It won't break on certain conditions like presence of tab characters in input file. 3. And finally for this command, it doesn't really matter how many newlines you have in input. It just finds time-stamp strings and treats them as record separator.

Comment: btw you approach can be refactored to this to avoid reliance on tab which might be present in input: **`tr '\n' '\1' < file | sed -E 's/\x1([0-9]{2}:)/\n\1/g; s/\x1$//g' | sort -t $'\1' | tr '\1' '\n'`**